# Spring boot with maven and tanuki wrapper

Tags: java, service, wrapper, tanuki

I have spring boot app and i want to run it as service. I am using tanuki wrapper to do so :

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate-daemons</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <logsDirectory>logs</logsDirectory>
                        <daemons>
                            <daemon>
                                <id>DataCopier</id>
                                <wrapperMainClass>org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp</wrapperMainClass>
                                <mainClass>com.myProject.mainClass</mainClass>
                                <platforms>
                                    <platform>jsw</platform>
                                </platforms>
                            </daemon>
                        </daemons>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

However how do i run this? I included it as plugin. I tried to `mvn install` it to see if this generates something but it does not generate anything in target folder. How do i run this then?